MPL for core C++ and MIT for python interface and others: is this sound?
I'm developing a high-performance algorithm library for robotics applications. The implementation consists of C++ core algorithms with Python bindings and YAML configuration support.
My objective is twofold: enabling commercial adoption while fostering contributions for algorithm optimization and bug fixes. To achieve this balance, I'm considering a dual-licensing approach:

Mozilla Public License (MPL) for the core C++ algorithms
MIT License for the Python interface and wheel distributions

My questions are:

Is this approach sound?
Would this licensing structure be problematic/annoying?


I am not fully up to date with how wheel distributions work, but I will assume that the wheel contains a compiled library of the C++ algorithms.
If my assumption is correct, then the wheel can be licensed under the MIT license, but it must also contain a notice for the users that the C++ algorithm sources can be obtained under the MPL license and how they can be obtained.
Every application that directly or indirectly depends on the C++ algorithms needs to include such a notice in their distribution to satisfy the MPL requirements.
With that in mind, your approach is sound, but also contains an annoyance for me. The annoyance is the indirect dependency on the MPL license, because there is a high risk that the information regarding the MPL code gets lost somewhere in the dependency chain (especially when the intervening dependencies have a very permissive license) and my distribution accidentally infringes upon the MPL license requirements.
The annoyance would be gone if the C++ algorithms and the Python bindings would have the same license. And if it is both MPL license, that still allows use in a commercial, closed-source, application.
